# Kernel doesn't seem to be signed for Secureboot. (linux-image-5.17.5-76051705-generic )

Tags: linux-kernel, grub2, secure-boot

I've been trying to get secure boot enabled but don't manage to do it. I have installed shim and Grub correctly with

```bsh
sudo apt install shim-signed && sudo grub-install
```

However, when I boot, I get "bad shim signature" and have to disable secure boot again.

I have checked the kernel's signature with

```bsh
sbverify /boot/vmlinuz-5.17.5-76051705-generic
```

The result tells me "no signature table present". When I check the 5.15 version of the kernel, I get the proper signature by Canonical.

How can I get the current version of the kernel with all modules signed?

If I run the 5.15 version, I cannot move my mouse at all, and some keys on the keyboard won't work. This problem happens on 5.15 regardless of whether secure boot is disabled or enabled.